# PHP trying to display data from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to display records from my database with this code:

```
<?php 

include("carconnect.php");

$sqlGet ="SELECT * FROM cars";
$sqlData = mysqli_query($connect , $sqlGet) or die ("Error retrieving data!");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlData , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['car'];
}

?>
```

Basically all I'm getting on the webpage is the Error retrieving data message..

UPDATED: Speech marks shouldnt have been there sorry.

Comment: Remove the `"` before `mysqli_query`

Comment: @Daan that was a typo still doesnt work when i take it away

Comment: Try `mysqli_query($connect , $sqlGet) or die (mysqli_error($connect));`. You'll get exact error message and try to debug it.

Comment: @SreelalPMohan "No database selected" was the message...

Comment: Then error is in `carconnect.php`

Answer (score 0):

There is `"` in `$sqlData = "mysqli_query` before `mysqli_query`. Please remove it or try the following code.

Try

```
include("carconnect.php");

$sqlGet ="SELECT * FROM cars";
$sqlData = mysqli_query($connect , $sqlGet) or die ("Error retrieving data!");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlData , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['car'];
}
```

Comment: " was a typo when writing out this question..sorry. Have edited question

Answer (score 0):

**Use the another simple and very easy way:**

```
<?php 
$host='hostname';
$dbuser='dbusername';
$dbpass='pass';
$dbname='databasename';
$conn= new mysqli('$hostname','$dbuser','$dbpass','$dbname');

$sqlGet ="SELECT * FROM cars";
$result=$conn->query('$sqlget');

while($sqlData= $result->fetch_assoc())
{
   echo $row['car'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
include("carconnect.php");
$sqlGet ="SELECT * FROM cars";
$sqlData = mysqli_query($connect , $sqlGet) or die ("Error retrieving data!");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlData , MYSQLI_NUM);
foreach ($row as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```